# When an avatar is displayed in an expanded question link in chat, it doesn't have a hat

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, winter-bash-2013, onebox

When you paste a link to a question into chat with no surrounding text, it gets oneboxed. Duh.

There's an avatar in the onebox. It doesn't have Winter Bash hats. It maybe should.

Comment: The horror... it's worse than being naked!